# Character and word count functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS that has a lot of redundant functionality, and it works but looks unseemly.

I would love some assistance with making this more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself):

```
// This provides character & word counter functionality

counter = function() {
    var body_value = $('#post_body').val();
    var title_value = $('#post_title').val();       

    if (body_value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCountBody').html(0);
        $('#totalCharsBody').html(0);
        return;
    }

    if (title_value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCountTitle').html(0);
        return;
    }

    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var wordCountBody = body_value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
    var totalCharsBody = body_value.length;
    var wordCountTitle = title_value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;

    $('#wordCountBody').html(wordCountBody);
    $('#totalCharsBody').html(totalCharsBody);
    $('#wordCountTitle').html(wordCountTitle);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#count').click(counter);
    $('#post_body').change(counter);
    $('#post_body').keydown(counter);
    $('#post_body').keypress(counter);
    $('#post_body').keyup(counter);
    $('#post_body').blur(counter);
    $('#post_body').focus(counter);
    $('#post_title').change(counter);
    $('#post_title').keydown(counter);
    $('#post_title').keypress(counter);
    $('#post_title').keyup(counter);
    $('#post_title').blur(counter);
    $('#post_title').focus(counter);        
});
```

Comment: Two pointers: Firstly, jQuery event handler assignments, like most jQuery selection methods, return `this`. Secondly, `jQuery.on` accepts an object parameter for assigning handlers to multiple events.

Comment: Why would you not want to count anything if either body or title are empty (but not necessarily the other)?

Comment: Where is `ready` declared/assigned?

Comment: @Bergi - above `counter`. I updated the question to include that code. It was irrelevant to this issue, so I left it out for brevity.

Comment: If `ready` is irrelevant to the question, it's better to remove its usages not to add its declaration :-)

Comment: @Bergi Well I would like to DRY that up too, i.e. the `document.ready()` call for that function relative to this, so everything is all DRY. That's why I put it in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks mostly fine—if you're just performing this specific functionality in one place, some repetition is okay—but there's one thing that could definitely be simplified. Your `ready` function could be reduced to simply this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#count').click(counter);
    $('#post_body, #post_title').on('change keydown keypress keyup blur focus', counter);
});
```

---

If, however, you really wanted to reduce all repetition, you could generalize the `counter` function until you ended up with a fairly reusable component.

Your counter function currently performs two actions (word counting and character counting) on two separate elements (the body and the title). To make the code as DRY as possible, you should employ the single responsibility principle to break up the function into composable bits.

```
function countUpdater(element, transformations) {
    return function () {
        var value = element.val();
        transformations.forEach(function (transformation) {
            transformation.display.html(value.length === 0 ? 0 : transformation.counter(value));
        });
    }
}

function wordCounter(value) {
    return value.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length;
}

function characterCounter(value) {
    return value.length;
}
```

Your event handler code would then become this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var changeEvents = 'change keydown keypress keyup blur focus';

    var bodyUpdater = countUpdater($('#post_body'), [
        { display: $('#wordCountBody'), counter: wordCounter },
        { display: $('#totalCharsBody'), counter: characterCounter },
    ]);
    var titleUpdater = countUpdater($('#post_title'), [
        { display: $('#wordCountTitle'), counter: wordCounter },
    ]);

    $('#count').click(function () {
        bodyUpdater();
        titleUpdater();
    });
    $('#post_body').on(changeEvents, bodyUpdater);
    $('#post_title').on(changeEvents, titleUpdater);
});
```

Is that better? Worse? Well, it's certainly less clear, but it's also much more reusable. If you're going to use this type of functionality many times, it might be worth it, but otherwise, I might prefer the simpler, more explicit version.

Comment: LOL...wow....thanks much for this. Yeh....I think it is definitely less clear. I like the top part of the post with the modification to the `document.ready(function)` though.

Comment: @marcamillion Yep, completely eradicating code repetition can often introduce layers of indirection or abstraction that you don't really need and can just clutter the code. In this case, I'm guessing the version you wrote it probably fine.

Comment: Very nice! I basically agree, I'd start with the asker's version and refactor only when I see I need that functionality elsewhere.  I'd just like to add that another reason for refactoring could be to make the code easily testable.  (Whether you want to test this stuff is arguable of course!)